# Check truthiness of props passed from mapStateToProps in functional react redux component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have 3 components, **TypeList**, **ConnectedType** (`=connect(mapStateToProps)(Type`), and **Type**. Type will receive props from both TypeList (`onClick, name`) passing props to ConnectedType as well as ConnectedType's mapStateToProps (`onMiniPokemonClick, miniPokemon`). How do I do a check to see if `miniPokemon` exists before mapping it out? Is it possible to do logic on a functional component or do I have to make it a class and create a helper function inside?

```
const Type = ({onClick, name, onMiniPokemonClick, miniPokemon}) => (
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
  >
    {name}
    <ul>
      {
        if (miniPokemon) {
          miniPokemon.map(function (pokemon, idx) {
            return (<MiniPokemon onClick={() => onMiniPokemonClick(pokemon.name)} name={pokemon.name}/>)
          })
        }
      }
    </ul>
  </li>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use brackets to allow a multiline function body

```
const Type = ({onClick, name, onMiniPokemonClick, miniPokemon}) => {
   // some logic   
   return (
      <li
        onClick={onClick}
      >...
      </li>
   )
}
```

Or if you just need to ensure that `miniPokemon` is an array when a null/undefined value comes through - you could supply a default argument:

```
({onClick, name, onMiniPokemonClick, miniPokemon = []})
```

Comment: THANKS! I know that {} only lets you evaluate expressions that are only 1liners, but how does putting this inside a return with () rather than the implicit return of es6's () in a function change it?

Comment: btw I put that in but seems like react's not going thru my if statement at all and still trying to map out miniPokemon regardless if it exists or not

Comment: I was thinking you may want to do some sort of logic prior to iteration and possibly return `null` or something if `miniPokemon` is empty or unset: if you are getting an array or undefined and want to ensure you have an array to iterate over you can use a default argument as noted in my updated answer